# Is there any better way to do sorting option?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

So, I'm trying to make option that will sort results from database. I found a way to do this, but I'm not sure it's best.

```
if(!isset($_GET['sort']) || $_GET['sort'] == 0) {
    $userquery = $DBH->query("SELECT users.id, users.username, users.name, users.joined, users.usergroup, user_groups.group_title FROM users INNER JOIN user_groups ON users.usergroup = user_groups.id ORDER BY users.id ASC");
    $userquery->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
} else {
    if($_GET['sort'] == 1) {
        $userquery = $DBH->query("SELECT users.id, users.username, users.name, users.joined, users.usergroup, user_groups.group_title FROM users INNER JOIN user_groups ON users.usergroup = user_groups.id ORDER BY users.username ASC");
        $userquery->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    } else if($_GET['sort'] == 2) {
        $userquery = $DBH->query("SELECT users.id, users.username, users.name, users.joined, users.usergroup, user_groups.group_title FROM users INNER JOIN user_groups ON users.usergroup = user_groups.id ORDER BY users.name ASC");
        $userquery->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    } else if($_GET['sort'] == 3) {
        $userquery = $DBH->query("SELECT users.id, users.username, users.name, users.joined, users.usergroup, user_groups.group_title FROM users INNER JOIN user_groups ON users.usergroup = user_groups.id ORDER BY user_groups.group_name ASC");
        $userquery->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to repeat the non-changing parts of the query over and over again. Just put that into a variable and append the `ORDER BY` clause to that string depending on the condition. Then use the string as the query parameter.

```
$querystring = "SELECT users.id, users.username, users.name, users.joined, users.usergroup, user_groups.group_title FROM users INNER JOIN user_groups ON users.usergroup = user_groups.id ORDER BY ";
switch($_GET['sort']) {
  case 1:
  $querystring.= "users.username ASC";
    break;
  case 2:
  $querystring.= "users.name ASC";
    break;
  case 3:
  $querystring.= "user_groups.group_name ASC";
    break;
case 0:
default:
  $querystring.= "users.id ASC";
    break;
}

$userquery = $DBH->query($querystring);
$userquery->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: I edited the answer to include a code example using a switch/case statement. Also, the fetch mode should be set before the query.

Comment: Why before the query?

Comment: After the query has been made, it's too late to tell it in which format to return the results, no? But now that I think of it, calling the method on the variable before it  contains an object is also nonsense... I'll edit that again. I might be totally wrong and DBO is actually so flexible that you can change the format afterwards... Can't try it out right now.